# How to number output in list in bash?

Tags: bash, object

I want to number each line that gets outputted when i list a directory, so that instead of typing out the full name of the object, i can identify it with a number in the list. In Bash.

Ex. os-list is a directory I use to store numerous of objects that are ever changing. 
os1.xxx.iso is the object name.

From

```
 ls os-list

        os1-xxx.iso
        os2-xxx.iso

   What is the path?: os1-xxx.iso
```

To

```
       ls os-list

       [1]os1-xxx.iso
       [2]os2-xxx.iso

   What is the path? 1
```

What is the term that im looking for this kind of operation in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to number each line that gets outputted when i list a directory

For your exact desired output format:

```
ls | nl | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -r 's/^[0-9]*()/[\0]/' | sed 's/\t//'
```

or

```
ls | cat -n | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -r 's/^[0-9]*()/[\0]/' | sed 's/\t//'
```

If you only want to have number as reference, and not in your exact desired format then simply:

```
ls | cat -n
```

or

```
ls | nl
```

would suffice, `sed` pipe is added to enclose given number in square brackets and remove starting/trailing spaces to conform to your desired output. Admitedly, this could be done with `awk` as well, pipe is not optimized, just given as reference point.

Edit:
with `awk` like so:

```
ls | cat -n | awk '{print "[" NR "]"$2}'
```

Selecting filename based on index (example with index 12 given):

```
ls | cat -n | awk '{print "[" NR "]"$2}' | grep "^\[12\]" | sed 's/^\[12\]//'
```

Note of caution: this approach supposes that between listing and selecting no file is added (if file is added in between and your sort order is messed up 12th file in listing and 12th file in select might ended not being the same file).

Answer (score 1):

The command `select` can be used:

```
files=$(ls os-list)
select choice in ${files[@]}; do
   break
done
echo "${choice}"
```

You can modify this to your needs, just look for more examples with `select`.
I would change the prompt (`PS3="What is the path: "`) and replace the `break` in the `select` loop (check for a valid response).